# Return value on the argument list C#

Tags: c#

Will the following code always print out 3.0?

`testVal` appears twice in the assignment below, is it okay?

```
double calc(double a, double b)
{
    double result = a + b;
    return result;
}

static void main()
{
   double testVal = 1.0;
   double addThis = 2.0;

   testVal = calc(testVal, addThis);
   Console.WriteLine(testVal);
}
```

Comment: This code seems to be OK to print 3.0.

Comment: You must declare the variable `result` in the `calc` method. As written, this won't compile.

Comment: What @DanJ said is true, alternatively you can just do `return a + b;`

Comment: Thanks Dan J. I added the double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will always return 3. I don't know what your `--testVal` at the top of the sample is. The value of testVal is copied onto the stack before the code in the calc method is run. (`double` is a value type.) All parameters are read before the method is executed. The return value is copied into the local variable when the method is finished.

Comment: I'm guessing he's used to a scripting language that uses `--` for commenting. Lua does this, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The right side is evaluated first, then the value is placed in testVal.  For details see the [C# spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), section *14.14.1 Simple assignment*.

It says for the case of x = y where x is a variable and y is an expression:

> The value resulting from the evaluation and conversion of y is stored into the location given by the evaluation of x.